# My database values got wiped out after I manually configured the database in spring boot

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mysql-workbench

I tried to configure the a database connection in my spring boot application manually using Datasource, entityManager and transacitonManager and it worked. But When I stopped an re-run the application, it wiped out all the database values inside the database. I had to manually input new database values to test my Rest API URL on postman. After I stopped and re-ran the application again, my database value got wiped out out yet again. What could have been the reason for that?

Comment: Do you have spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto configuration on create-drop maybe?

Comment: "jpa. hibernate. ddl-auto explicitly and the standard Hibernate property values are none , validate , update , create-drop . Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on whether it thinks your database is embedded (default create-drop ) or not (default none )."

Comment: @KafFafOwn, yes I have set it up to "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update"

Comment: Which database is that? H2 maybe?

Comment: @KafKafOwn nope, its MySql

Comment: Odd, do you run any SQL DDL statements on startup?

Comment: @KafKafOwn Nope, I do not run any DDL statements

Comment: Nothing obvious, you will have to supply more details + code..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.